# Как отправить фото из Storage в ответе на запрос Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

На сервере Laravel в Storage есть фото 23.png
Нужно отправить ее клиенту так, чтобы через JS можно было отобразить это фото в DOM.
Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Пытался так:

```
        return response()->json(Storage::get('12.png'));
```

на что получил ошибку

InvalidArgumentException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file C:\OpenServer\domains\World Skills National\Server\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse.php on line 75

Comment: Так отправьте урлу ```return response()->json(['url' => Storage::url('12.png')])``` а гет отдаёт содержимое, на что вам и жалуется лара что она не может его привести к json

Comment: А так можно будет на странице вывести?

Comment: Для вывода фото нужно же будет написать путь "домен/storage/23.png"? Где "storage/23.png" это полученный с запроса путь?

Comment: У вас метод url сам это сделает если правильно залинковано всё

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое